# SMF [img] bbcode to html

Tags: php, bbcode, smf

I want to convert the [img] bbcode of SMF to HTML, it looks like this:

```
[img width=600 height=300]url[/img]
```

My script is this, but doesn't work, what's wrong?

```
$text = preg_replace("/\[img  width=(.*) height=(.*)\](.*)\[\/img\]/Usi", "<img src=\"\\3\" class=\"image\" style=\"width:\\1; height:\\2\" />", $text);
```

Comment: This question is has nothing to do with greediness.  It is a typo in your pattern.  You have two whitespaces before `width`, but your input only has one.  Proof: https://3v4l.org/aTUbA  Voting to close as **Off-topic: Typo** instead of answering.

Answer (score -1):

Your wild cards are being greedy.  Use `.*?` Instead of `.*`

Comment: $text = preg_replace("/\[img  width=(.*?) height=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/img\]/Usi", "<img src=\"\\3\" class=\"image\" style=\"width:\\1; height:\\2\" />", $text);


Still not works...